# Using Split arguments in other functions

Tags: python, for-loop, split

The code is suppose to take a string of multiple arguments and split them with the "Split()". It does do that, but it only passes the first argument to the "CheckList()". So if I type " 1 2 4" it will only pass "1" to CheckList. Everything else works as it should.

```
import re            

def CheckList(Start):
    DoIt = 0
    s = int(Start)
    End = s + 1
    End = str(End)
    for PodCheck in F.readlines():

        if re.match('Pod' + End, PodCheck.strip()):
            DoIt = 0

        if re.match('Pod' + Start, PodCheck.strip()):
            DoIt = 1

        if DoIt == 1:
            print PodCheck,   

    return

def Split(P):
    Pods = P.split()
    for Pod in Pods:
        CheckList(Pod)

    return

F = open("C:\Users\User\Desktop\IP_List.txt")

Pod = raw_input('What pod number would you like to check?: ')
Split(Pod.strip())
print 'Done'
```

Comment: How do you know it's only passing in the first argument and not just missing data during the `for PodCheck in...`?

Comment: That's just where i believed the error to be. It turns out I was very wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
for PodCheck in F.readlines():
```

The first call to `CheckList` uses up all the data in `F`.  Subsequent calls to `Checklist` skip the `for` loop because there is nothing left to read.

So after opening `F` your should read all of it's data.  Without changing too much of your code I would add this after you open your file:

```
F_lines = F.readlines()
```

And change to loop in `CheckList` to

```
for PodCheck in F_lines:
```

Comment: You're a hero, sir. Thank you!

Comment: The problem was what you said. To fix it I opened and closed the file in CheckList().